# Как через переменную выразить имя исходного файла 'php'?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

У меня есть файл 'eeea2dc5.php' мне нужно, чтобы код выразил название этой страницы так, чтобы не переписывать его вручную. Позже присвоить его имя переменной $filename

```
$filename ='';//?
```

Напишите, пожалуйста, код

Comment: `__FILE__` ....

Comment: @АндрейСмирнов `$filename = basename(__FILE__);`